# Perl inheritence or similar effect when assigning subroutines to scalars

Tags: perl, callback

I would like to assign a sub to a scalar as a callback and at the same time archive inheritance like behaviour i.e. in code below calling `foobar->warning()` or `foobar->croaking()` will trigger the function of the parent if no implementation is provided in class foobar. With the additional requirement I can assign it to a scalar.

The only way I could solve this is doing it the other way around in i.e. calling  'warning_check_child' in 'barqux' that will check if a specific implementation is available or execute its own code.

I'm hoping someone out there has a better solution so I can avoid the exist call in the start or at least confirm that there are no better way.

Thanks in advance

```
use strict;
use warnings;

warn "When methods accessed as class from foobar";    
foobar->warning();

my $sub;
# assign class method to sub reference does not work
# $sub = \&foobar->warning;
# $sub->();

# Have the sub in other package check for custom functionality
$sub = \&barqux::warning_check_child;
$sub->();

### Child class
package foobar;
use parent -norequire, 'barqux';

sub warning{
    warn "warning: foobar\n";
}  
sub warning_check_child{
    warn "warning: foobar";
}

### Parent class
package barqux;

sub warning{
    warn "warning: barqux\n";
}  
sub croaking{
    warn "croaking: barqux\n";
}
sub warning_check_child{
    if ( exists &foobar::warning_check_child ){
        foobar::warning_check_child()
    }
    else {
        warn "warning: barqux\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is rather unclear. Are you hoping to be able to call `BarQux->warning_check_child` in a way that will execute `FooBar::warning_check_child` if there is no `BarQux::warning_check_child`?

Comment: I'm hoping to be able to call `BarQux::warning_check_child` if `FooBar::warning_check_child` does not exists. Normally I would use inheritance but I need to be able to assign it to a scalar as a callback.

Comment: Is your "object" (i.e. the thing you want to inherit behavior) supposed to be a code reference?

Comment: Be wary of [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Your setup sounds very odd, so perhaps there is a more standard approach to a root problem that you're not considering.

Comment: @Miller Thanks for pointing out the XY problem I will keep it in mind for the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need [`UNIVERSAL::can`](https://metacpan.org/pod/UNIVERSAL), which returns a *reference* to a method if the class can perform that method, either directly or by inheritance.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sub = FooBar->can('warning_check_child');
$sub->();


### Parent class
package BarQux;

sub warning{
   warn "warning: BarQux\n";
}  

sub croaking{
   warn "croaking: BarQux\n";
}    

sub warning_check_child{
   warn "warning_check_child: BarQux\n";
}


### Child  class
package FooBar;
use base 'BarQux';

sub croaking{
   warn "croaking: FooBar\n";
}
```

**output**

```
warning_check_child: BarQux
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to up vote the answer but my rep is not high enough.

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks are code references, Perl objects are blessed references, therefore you can bless a CODE reference to create a callback with inheritance. If you convert `Foo::warning` into a factory, I think you can get the behavior you're after.

```
use 5.016; # needed for __SUB__
use strict;
use warnings;

package Bar {
    sub warning {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self  = sub {
            __SUB__->warning_check_child();
            say 'Bar::warning';
        };
        return bless $self, $class;
    }

    sub warning_check_child {
        my $self = shift;
        say 'Bar::warning_check_child';
    }
}

package Foo {
    use base 'Bar';

    sub warning {
        my $class = shift;
        my $self  = sub {
            __SUB__->warning_check_child();
            say 'Foo::warning'
        };
        return bless $self, $class;
    }
}

package main {
    my $f = Foo->warning();
    $f->();
}
```

The output is

```
Bar::warning_check_child
Foo::warning
```

If Foo adds a `warning_check_child` method, that would be called instead.

Note: I'm using `__SUB__` here as another way of writing `$self` since the object is the subroutine. If you're limited to a version of Perl prior to 5.16 you can pre-declare `$self` first and create a closure over it instead:

```
sub warning {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self;
    $self = sub {
        $self->warning_check_child();
        say 'Foo'
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}
```